# Were Pokédexes used other than to look up Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

If I recall right, a Pokédex revealed a ghost Pokemon that was creating an illusion. Were they ever used in a novel manner, like to communicate or identify tracks?

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9dex - Yes. To track the health of Pokemon, as an ID badge, as a map, as a light source, to transfer pokemon, etc etc.

Comment: Interestingly, Pokedexes from regions other than Kalos and Alola include a Pokemon's footprint as part of the info they provide on any given Pokemon. However, at no point is this actually utilised in any meaningful way (such as identifying tracks), in the games, anime or manga series, which is probably why the feature was removed in Gen VI.

Comment: Not sure when a Pokedex was used to reveal a ghost, though, I thought you specifically needed a Silph Scope for that?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo: I believe the OP is referring to an early episode of the anime, which makes me wonder whether is question is supposed to be anime-only.

Comment: I think "Dexter" was an especially capable Pokedex in the anime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the Episode you are looking for is [this one](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP020), whereby the Pokédex picks up an impersonating Gastly.

---

## Yes, the Pokédex has been used for other situations other than identifying a Pokémon

Taken from Bulbapedia:

> They may give background information on the habitat or activities of a Pokémon in the wild or other information on the Pokémon's history or anatomy. Pokédex entries also include height, weight, cry, footprint (prior to Generation VI), location, other forms, and a picture of the Pokémon.

---

In Original Series Ep 110, [The Stun Spore Detour](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP110), Misty uses Ash's Pokédex **to search** for a natural antidote for paralysis.

[image]

---

In Diamond & Pearl Ep 3, Paul uses his Pokedex to check the stats and moves of the Starly he caught.

[image]

<sub>Courtesy of @ThunderForge</sub>

---

In Journeys Ep 88, Goh uses his Pokedex to mimic the cry of Ash's Dragonite, to lure out a wild Kingdra.

[image]

<sub>Courtesy of @Stef</sub>

---

In Pokémon Adventures, Blue uses his Pokédex to 'transfer' his Porygon into Yellow's Pokédex.

> The Mankey troupe promptly starts to lose focus with their leader's distraction. **Coordinating with Yellow, Blue sends his Porygon through his Pokédex to Yellow's, which emerges through Yellow's Pokédex and faints Primeape with a Tri Attack**.
>
> <sub>Bulbapedia - Book 5, Chapter 55 Pokémon Adventures - The Primeape Directive</sub>

You could say that the Pokédex was used as a method of communication in that scenario.

Comment: In [Diamond & Pearl episode 3](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP003), Paul uses his Pokédex to check the moves known by his three newly captured Starly, and chooses to release the two that don't know Aerial Ace.

Comment: In [Pokemon Journeys](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/JN088), Goh uses his rotomphone/pokedex to broadcast the cry of a Dragonite, as a lure for a wild Kingdra.